# npregiv in R: dimension error

Tags: r, stata, dimension

In order to compute a non parametric IV regression, I have read in a `.dta` file from Stata where I am used to working.  I then subset my vectors for `y` (dependent), `z` (endogenous with y), and `w` (instrument for z) - using `y` as an example:

```
y = data.frame(data$y)
```

and then my multivariate exogenous x matrix in a similar fashion.  Executing

```
model = npregiv(y, z, w, x)
```

I expected things to work, as y is nx1, z is nx1, w is nx1, and x is nx4.  In `npregiv`, z, w, and x are allowed to be multivariate, and y must be univariate (which it is).  However, I get the error message after executing the command:

```
Error in tww[, , 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

What is `tww[.]`?

Comment: Please provide a small, reproducible example of data and the code you're running.  My guess is that one of your variables (`data$*`) does not have the dimensionality required of the inputs to `npregiv`.

Comment: You also need to say where this function is coming from. (Your first line is almost certainly the wrong way to start. It's possible that `dfrm <- data.frame(y=y, z=z,w=w)` followed by `data=dfrm` in the regression call would work.)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: In terms of an example, creating any vectors of the form `a=c(1,2,3,4,5)`, `a=data.frame(a)` for y, z, w, and x.  For y, the documentation requires it to be a one-dimensional vector, but I use the data.frame anyway since `ncol(y)` returns NULL if it is not in a data frame.  Without the data frame R returns "Error: training and evaluation data have unequal number of columns".  Otherwise, running `model=npregiv(y=y,z=z,w=w,x=x)` gives the tww[.] error.

@DWin, the `data=dfrm` did not work for me.  Doesn't the command require the y,z,w,x data to be entered separately?

Comment: @kirk Sounds like the `npregiv` package has problems. Might be better if it called `NCOL` rather than `ncol` .  But in either case: `data.frame` is not the same as a `matrix` .  You could always set the `dim` attribute of `y` to `c(1,length(y))` if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, I created a data frame with all variables relevant to the regression including the vector y and matricies z, w, and x.  Instead of calling `npregiv(y=y, z=z, w=w,x=x)`, it is also necessary to specify the evaluation data (which it says it takes from x, y, and z by default): `npregiv(y=y, z=z, w=w, x=x, zeval=z, weval=w, xeval=x)`.